# enqueue script for specific shortcode

Tags: theme-development, shortcode

I've created some shortcodes and for some of these, I need to load particular scripts on demand.

I've included by default in my function.php file

```
vendor.js
myscript.js
```

When i load the shortcode, i need to include a separate script between the two above (meaning that myscript.js requires the new script to be included before it to work).

I've created the shortcode like this:

```
function callbackService()
{
    ob_start();    
    get_template_part('hg_custom_shortcodes/callback');
    return ob_get_clean();   
}
add_shortcode('callbackService', 'callbackService');
```

the template is loading an angular app.

I then tried to load my script (the one that needs to be included only when the shortcode is loaded) by changing the snippet above to this:

```
function callbackService()
{
    ob_start();    
    wp_enqueue_script('angular-bundle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/scripts/angular-bundle.js', array(), false, true);
    get_template_part('hg_custom_shortcodes/callback');
    return ob_get_clean();   
}
add_shortcode('callbackService', 'callbackServhowever
```

The script is included, hovewer i think it's included after `myscript.js` and the whole shortcode (angular app) is not working as "Angular is not defined".

How can i tell the enqueue to load the script after?
I know that usually i would change the `add_action()` priority, but in this particular case there's no `add_action` involved and i don't know what else to try.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Can you work with the dependancies parameter? (currently `array()` in your code)

Comment: Hi, i did try using this already with no luck

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`wp_enqueue_script` is not going to work in a shortcode, this is because of the loading order.

You could use `wp_register_script` and then you could `wp_enqueue_script` in you shortcode function like this example:

```
// Front-end
function front_end_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'example-js', '//example.com/shared-web/js/example.js', array(), null, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'front_end_scripts' );
```

Then you use this in your shortcode:

```
function example_shortcode() {

   wp_enqueue_script( 'example-js' );
   return; // dont forget to return something

}
add_shortcode( 'example-shortcode', 'example_shortcode' );
```

Furthermore, you could use [`has_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) to check if a shortcode is loaded:

```
function custom_shortcode_scripts() {
global $post;
if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-shortcode') ) {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script');
}
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_shortcode_scripts');
```

Comment: I did try with register first and then enqueu but with no luck. I wasn't aware of the has_shortcode. I'll try to use this and see if that helps. Thanks for now

Comment: @Nick You're welcome :) Glad it worked.

Comment: This answer is mostly incorrect. `wp_enqueue_script` works fine on its own in a Shortcode, you don't have to register the script first. Script registration is a convenience feature, note that `wp_enqueue_script` accepts all the same arguments as `wp_register_script`. In either case, WordPress can't time travel and load order is exactly the same, late enqueue works because the script is output by the `wp_footer()` function.

Comment: @Milo It didn't work for me. I have developed a theme and two plugins. Try for yourself. Maybe I did something wrong, but I doubt it.

Comment: Tested and confirmed that registration is not necessary.

Comment: Okay. Is this the same with wp_register_style / wp_enqueue_style?

Comment: Yes, since version 3.3 stylesheets can be enqueued after `wp_head` has run and the [`print_late_styles`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/print_late_styles/) function will automatically output them when `wp_footer` is called, right before scripts are output. The register functions are handy when a script or style could potentially be enqueued in multiple places (a shortcode, a widget, a template, etc.), but you want to have the details of that script/style, like filename and version, in one central location.

Comment: Okay, that's strange, because I try to enqueue something in my theme and it didn't work in a shortcode. (I don't know anymore if it was wp_enqueue_script or wp_enqueue_style). I will try later. Now I need to make my theme Glutenberg compatible. Again thanks for your clarification.

Answer (score 2):

Would [`has_shortcode`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_shortcode) help you solve your problem?

On the codex there's an example,

> Enqueue some script when some post uses some shortcode

```
function custom_shortcode_scripts() {
    global $post;
    if( is_a( $post, 'WP_Post' ) && has_shortcode( $post->post_content, 'custom-shortcode') ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'custom-script');
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_shortcode_scripts');
```

Answer (score 1):

We can indeed conditionally load CSS and JS files via shortcode without using any *overly elaborate* functions:

First, let's assume we registered all of our CSS/JS files previously (perhaps when `wp_enqueue_scripts` ran)

```
function prep_css_and_js() {
     wp_register_style('my-css', $_css_url);
     wp_register_script('my-js', $_js_url);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'prep_css_and_js', 5 );
```

Next, lets examine our shortcode function:

```
function my_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
  if( ! wp_style_is( "my-css", $list = 'enqueued' ) ) { wp_enqueue_style('my-css'); }
  if( ! wp_script_is( "my-js", $list = 'enqueued' ) ) { wp_enqueue_script('my-js'); }
  ...
}
```

Simple. Done.
**Ergo: we can "conditionally load" css/js files, (only when [shortcode] runs).**

Let's consider the following ideology:

- We want to load certain CSS/JS files (but only when shortcode is triggered)
- Maybe we do not want those files to load on every page, or at all if the shortcode is not used on a page/post. (light weight)
- We can accomplish this by making sure WP registers ALL of the css/js files prior to calling the shortcode and prior to the enqueue.
- *IE: Maybe during my `prep_css_and_js()` function I load ALL .css/.js files that are in certain folders...*

Now that WP see's them as registered scripts, we can indeed call them, conditionally, based on a verity of situations, including but not limited to `my_shortcode_func()`

Benefits: (no MySQL, no advanced functions and no filters needed)

- this is "WP orthodix", elegant, fast loading, easy and simple
- allows compilers/minifiers to detect such scripts
- uses the WP functions (wp_register_style/wp_register_script)
- compatible with more themes/plugins that might want to de-register those scripts for a verity of reasons.
- will not trigger multiple times
- very little processing or code is involved

References:

- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_script_is
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style
- https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_scripts/