# Enqueue CSS and Script only if needeed

Tags: css, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

How can I enqueue a CSS code **only** on the pages which use that CSS?

Usually it's quite easy to know if a particular CSS or JS is used on a WordPress Post: it's enough to check if the shortcode is used in that post.

Is there any WP functionality to support the developer in this task?

Comment: Yes, you can `wp_enqueue_script()` asset in your shortcode method/function. So only when shortcode is used, asset loads.

Comment: @sandrodz: thanks. I just realized that 99% of WP plugin developers ignore this? Or don't they care about performance? Why to load JS or CSS when not needed?

Comment: I've found a similar solution here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/191316/64590

Comment: @sandrodz it's not so easy, because you have to enqueue script/style before it is printed (styles should be printed in header, and shortcodes are processed after header is printed).

Comment: @Revious You can achieve that, but it doesn't make much sense. CSS/JS files should be cached by browsers. Also, they should get combined and minified, so loading different set of JS/CSS files on different pages is rather harmful for performance.

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż: yes, maybe with minification is doesn't make a big difference. However the browser cache doesn't help that much, in a real production scenario, since 80% of visitors are "non returning" and see 1,3 pages..

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż: I'd like also to ask about a small issue.. I'm trying with Breeze caching and it dowsnt minify the css files.. if I cannot solve can I open a new questione and ask for help?

Comment: @Revious still, combine and minify - it will save lot more bandwidth and requests than loading different set of files...

Comment: @KrzysiekDróżdż Did I say it was easy? yes you first register assets, then enqueue.

Comment: @Revious See my answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/317186/149484